# No developer settings in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Yesterday I was studying iOS development. I had just updated my Xcode and was finally able to deploy my apps to my iPhone. However, all of a sudden, my iPhone got a weird bug where it wasn't working at all. I restarted it, only to find that the developer section in settings was gone. I thought it might be some bugs from the beta version I was using, and decided to finally do the update (I had my memory all used up, so I didn't do it sooner in order to not delete anything). I thought that would fix my issue, and at least give my iPhone developer rights again. But it didn't. I've been searching for ways to do it since last night and I am unable to find anything recent, as they are all for older versions of iOS or Xcode. I tried them, but either they just don't work, or the path they use is now not existent.

Any ideas what that could be and how I could fix it?